# Strange behaviour when printing/reading time

Tags: c++, time, c++11, timezone, c++-chrono

I am trying to save `std::time_point` into a `std::stream` and read it back. One problem is that using the standard functions 'loses' an hour somewhere. I.e., the time I read is 1 hour behind the time I write. I suspect that I need to set up daylight saving somewhere. I put together a small program that prints time to a `std::stringstream` and reads it back.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>

using std::chrono::system_clock;
namespace chrono = std::chrono;

void test();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::stringstream ss;

    auto start = system_clock::now();

    std::time_t ts = system_clock::to_time_t(start);

    std::tm time_out = *std::localtime(&ts);
    ss << std::put_time(&time_out, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z") << '\n';

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;

    std::tm time_in;
    ss >> std::get_time(&time_in, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z");

    std::cout << "Are time dsts equal? : " <<
    (time_out.tm_isdst == time_in.tm_isdst) << '\n';

    std::time_t rawTime = std::mktime(&time_in);
    auto end = std::chrono::system_clock::from_time_t(rawTime);

    std::cout << "Are time points equal? : " << (start == end) << '\n';

    // print the trouble makers
    std::time_t start_time = system_clock::to_time_t(start);
    std::time_t end_time = system_clock::to_time_t(end);

    std::cout << "times: \n"
    << '\t' << std::put_time(std::localtime(&start_time), "%c %z") << '\n'
    << '\t' << std::put_time(std::localtime(&end_time), "%c %z") << '\n';

    // this is a source of strange behaviour...
//    std::cout << "Difference: "
//    << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::seconds>(start - end).count()
//    << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The strangest thing is that the program prints the following:

```
Are time dsts equal? : 1
Are time points equal? : 0
times: 
Tue Dec 11 19:26:24 2012 +0000
Tue Dec 11 19:26:24 2012 +0000
```

And when I uncomment the 3 lines at the end of the program (printing the difference between the time points) the result is:

```
Are time dsts equal? : 0
Are time points equal? : 0
times: 
Tue Dec 11 19:29:40 2012 +0000
Tue Dec 11 18:29:40 2012 +0000
Difference: 3600
```

Notice that dst(daylight saving time) is suddenly not equal and neither are the times.

I am using libc++ on Mac OS X 10.8.2 with XCode46-DP2. The clang++ versions I am using are `Apple clang version 4.1` and `clang version 3.2 (trunk 167239)`

I guess my questions are:
A) As to the 1 hour difference, is this a bug in my library or am I not using the standard functions correctly? (The latter would not surprise me...)

B) What is going on with the code when I uncomment the three lines at the end of my program? This looks like a bug to me. Anyone care to try it on their platform?

Comment: For chrono/io you may like to use boost chrono_io http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.io

Comment: @JohanLundberg:  Both of these are my code, so switching is not likely to fix things.  Investigating...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we're looking at a bug with the `%Z` specifier, and *maybe* with the `%z` specifier as well, not sure yet.

I will look into the cause of these bugs more.  However I wanted to go ahead and post to get you a workaround.  I believe if you zero-initialize your input `tm`, and always assume it is with respect to your local timezone, then you will eliminate your errors:

```
std::tm time_in{0};
```

Comment: Thanks, that works fine. I was using `time_in.is_dst = 0` and that worked as well.

Comment: On a related note, what 'time type' would you recommend for a timestamp? I am using this for entries in a cache and would like to be able to discard old entries. I am using `time_t timestamp = system_clock::to_time_t(system_clock::now())` to create the timestamp but I am not sure whether it is the best choice.

Comment: It depends on your precision needs.  But on Mac OS X 10.8.2, if you're compiling in 64 bit mode, which is the default, `time_t` has a precision of seconds and takes up 64 bits.  `system_clock::time_point` is also a suitable time stamp, also takes up 64 bits, and has precision of microseconds.  If you need a time stamp with precision of nanoseconds, then on this platform you could go with `high_resolution_clock::time_point`, which is also 64 bits.